# Print table via jQuery/ajax array

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

I am trying to print array in jquery, I want it to run every 4 sec and want to clear data written in previous loop before it print out again after 4 second. but it is adding the data(rows) rather than replacing.

```
    function sendRequest(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'<?php echo site_url('ajax/ajax_buybtc'); ?>',
    success: 
    function(result){
        var jsonResult = JSON.parse(result);
        jsonResult.forEach(function(data) {
    var newTr = "<tr>";
   newTr += '<tr> <td style="text-align:center;"><a><span class="label label- 
   warning">Sell</span></a></td>';
   newTr += "<td>" + data.xbtc + "</td>";
   newTr += "<td>" + data.rate + "</td>";
   newTr += "<td>" + data.xpkr + "</td>";
   newTr += "</tr>";
   $('.table > tbody:last-child').append(newTr);
}); 



        setTimeout(function(){
            sendRequest(); //this will send request again and again;
        }, 4000);
    }
});
}
```

> Here is the HTML part

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed" style=" width:100%; float:left; border:3px solid white; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px white">  
          <tbody>


                 <tr>
                  <td style="text-align:center;"><b>Action</b></td>
                  <td style="text-align:center;"><b>BTC</b></td>
                  <td style="text-align:center;"><b>BID</b></td>
                  <td style="text-align:center;"><b>PKR</b></td>
            </tr>



                 <tr class="messages">
                 <td style="text-align:center;"><a><span class="label label-warning">Sell</span></a></td>
                 <td  style="text-align:center;"></td>
                 <td  style="text-align:center;"></td>
                <td  style="text-align:center;"></td>
            </tr>

                 </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: what's your desired result?

Comment: can i post a screenshot in here to let you see?

Comment: yes, anything that will help others identify your problem. can i look at your full jquery code?

Comment: i uploaded a screenshot above plz check. why it isn't text going to next line when second time loop run

Comment: add **tr** in start and in end also.

Comment: @ShivKumarBaghel in html it is added. are you talking about adding it in jquery?

Comment: i uploaded code have a look :)

Comment: solved. thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistake in your code. I fix it for you. Also, I add `class="messages"` to `tr` tag.

```
jsonResult.forEach(function(data) {
  var newTr = "";    // I delete the value to avoid double tr declaration
  newTr += '<tr class="messages"> <td style="text-align:center;"><a><span class="label label-warning">Sell</span></a></td>';
  newTr += "<td>" + data.xbtc + "</td>";
  newTr += "<td>" + data.rate + "</td>";
  newTr += "<td>" + data.xpkr + "</td>";
  newTr += "</tr>";
  $('.table tr.messages').remove();        // remove the existing one
  $('.table > tbody:last-child').append(newTr);
});
```

Before you add the new `tr`, remove the existing `tr` with class messages first. I declare the class name as messages to match with your HTML.

Comment: when i copy paste this code it gives error in console. jquery.js:1586 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <tr class="messages"> <td style="text-align:center;"><a><span class="label label-warning">Sell</span></a></td><td>1.1261261261261262</td><td>888</td><td>995</td></tr>

Answer (score 1):

[image]add **tr** for table row. refer below updated code.

```
var newTr = "<tr>";
newTr += "<tr> <td style="text-align:center;"><a><span class="label label-warning">Sell</span></a></td>";
newTr += "<td>" + data.xbtc + "</td>";
newTr += "<td>" + data.rate + "</td>";
newTr += "<td>" + data.xpkr + "</td>";
newTr += "</tr>";

$('.table > tbody:last-child').append(newTr);
```

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle or code snippet for JS+HTML+CSS is possible.

Comment: try to use `.append` in `tbody` of table.  `$('. table > tbody:last-child').append(jsonResult);`

Comment: it works fine but ever time it runs, it adds data at the end of table but i want to clear data before it posts again

Comment: please post/edit your code with `POST` request structure also.

Comment: use `$(".table > tbody").html("");` to clear data before POST

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You missed the `tr` in your code. Now try this:

```
jsonResult.push('<tr><td style="text-align:center;"><a><span class="label label-warning">Sell</span></a></td>');
        jsonResult.push("<td>" + data.xbtc + "</td>");
        jsonResult.push("<td>" + data.rate + "</td>");
        jsonResult.push("<td>" + data.xpkr + "</td></tr>");

});
    $(".messages").html(jsonResult.join(""));
```

Comment: plz see above pic

Comment: It's some issue with your table structure. Can you update the code of the table, I mean the `<thead>` , <tbody> and everything. If possible include your css as well

Comment: it works well with static data , or even with php loop, it just gone wrong when add <tr> to the code

Comment: Check whether your DOM is arranged properly. This not syncing issue happens when the DOM is not arranged well. If update me with your code